# Sample equal number of keys in Spark RDD

Tags: apache-spark, partition

I have a key value RDD, where the keys can be anything between `1` and `5`. The number of records in the RDD is in millions. I need to output RDD having 10,000 records of each key.

Sample RDD [(String, String)] for 3 distinct keys:

```
1 a
2 b
3 b
2 c
1 d
2 e
2 f
2 c
1 d
3 e
2 f
```

If I need two any 2 records of each key, output may be:

```
1 a
1 f
2 c
2 d
3 c
3 d
```

Comment: I don't understand you should clarify what is a,b,c... and what is your liked structure

Comment: Where are you running into a problem doing this? What is the actual output you're getting to compare with what you expect?

Answer (score 2):

`sampleByKeyExact` should do the trick:

```scala
def sampleByKeyUniform[T: ClassTag, U: ClassTag](
    rdd: RDD[(T, U)], n: Long, withReplacement: Boolean = false) = {
  rdd.sampleByKeyExact(withReplacement,
    rdd.countByKey.map{case (k, v) => k -> n.toDouble / v})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `reduceByKey` on your `RDD` to count how many times each shows up and then use `filter` to only get those with `count > 10000`

Comment: reduceByKey is not an option. The data set is very huge, that's why I am taking sample. ReduceByKey and then taking equal samples is taking a long time. Though thanks for the answer.